# Any way to replace navigation item on UINavigationController without pushing view controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I've created a view controller that's within the view controller hierarchy of a UINavigationController. This view controller contains a full-frame container view that displays the view of a child view controller.

I'd ideally like to display the items associated with the child view controller's navigation item (i.s., `title` and `rightBarButtonItems`) instead of the navigation item of the view controller that contains the container view.

My initial reaction is simply to set `viewController.navigationItem = childViewController.navigationItem` but `navigationItem` is read-only. My second reaction is to set the associated items themselves, e.g.:

```
viewController.navigationItem.title = childViewController.navigationItem.title;
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = childViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;
```

With swizzling, I'm also able to detect when the child view controller's navigation item's properties are set and update accordingly. However, if the child view controller's navigation item's properties are updated without replacement (e.g., `title` changes text color, `rightBarButtonItem` is disabled), these changes are not reflected.

Is there any way of achieving the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hello sir instead of setting childviewcontroller navigation item you can set parentviewcontroller's navigation item.

I mean to say before loading child view controller you can set parentviewcontroller's navigation bar Item if you know childviewcontroller's navigatio bar item value.

I have one more question if you child view controller is inside container how does it have own navigation bar because it would be scrollable so better to set parent view controller's navigation bar before loading child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my problem was elsewhere and that the approach outlined in my question works as desired. x_x

To make this answer more useful, here are more details of my approach:

- I created a category on UINavigationItem and swizzled the methods `-[setTitle:]` and `-[setRightBarButtonItems:]` using Mattt Thompson's tutorial (http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). The swizzled methods simply post custom NSNotifications `UINavigationItemTitleDidChange` and `UINavigationItemRightBarButtonItemsDidChange` respectively.
- In `-[prepareForSegue:sender:]` I extract the destination view controller of my embed segue and store it in a custom property `childViewController` on my view controller.
- In the setter for my view controller's `childViewController` I add observers to my custom UINavigationItem notifications using the navigation item of my child view controller as the object.
- When each of these notifications are received, I update the title and rightBarButtonItems of my view controller's navigation item, respectively.

The "elsewhere" in my own fix was that my child view controller wasn't updating its right bar button items when I thought it was, so it appeared as if the view controller presenting it wasn't obtaining its right bar button items.